# When using UIActivityViewController to share @[dataFileURL, @"text"] via messages app, the text is not included

Tags: message, ios13, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a simple UIActivityViewController to share a data file and some text.

The text is required because, since iOS 13, it's no longer intuitive how to open a file sent in messages.

My issue is, when I choose Messages as the option to send, it attaches the file, but not the text.

Prior to iOS13, it used to send the file in one message, and the text in a follow up.

If I share to Mail, or save to Files, both the text and the data are included.

If I share an NSURL that's simply a web address, and text, then both are shared in the same message.

It's only when I try to share an NSURL that points to a data source, and text, that only the data file is sent.

Here's my code:

```
    //Get NSURL for file
    NSURL *dataUrl = [AppData data:zippedData toPlnUrl:fileName]; //zipped data

    NSString *subject = @“PolyNome files”;

    NSString * textToShare = @"Check out these PolyNome Presets. Learn how to import here ->”];

    NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://polynome.net/importing"]; 

    NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare,website,dataUrl];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

    [activityVC setValue:subject forKey:@"subject"];

    activityVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = self.shareButton;


    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So, for example, if `NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare,website];` then that works and both text and url are included in one message.

As soon as I add `dataUrl` as an element at any position in the array, then that's the only thing that gets shared in messages - all other things are omitted.

This is driving me crazy since the only reason I need to include the import instructions is because iOS 13 made it **very** complicated to import the file from messages (you have to tap the avatar at the top of messages, tap "info", find "attachments", tap an attachment, then tap the share button, then choose "More...", then choose the app.)

Any advice much appreciated!